# Show View's title

Tags: 7, views

Block - Move the view to content. It shows it's title.
The [Insert view](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) module doesn't show any view's title. I need insert view module as well as it can display title. May I know how to solve this?

Many Thanks

Comment: please describe your problem properly. What have you done and what do you want?

Answer (score 1):

To remove View Title, you have to edit the `Title` field of the view and provide `<none>` or leave it blank.